# Redirect to non-www with HTTPS

Tags: apache-2.4, redirect, https, lets-encrypt

I installed an apache webserver and created a website. Let's Encrypt is used for https. I followed the auto-configuration process and the non-www url works fine. But if I want to redirect `https://www` to `https://xxxxx.com` with a `.htaccess` it doesn't work.

I tried with the following settings:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

`mod_rewrite` is enabled.

Comment: What is the error you get ? Do you have any rewrite logs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, is the certificate even valid for the www-Host? If not, get a second one for the www-host and put that a separate `<VirtualHost *:443>`.

If the certificate is valid for the domain and the www-host, it sounds to me as if there is a `ServerAlias` for the www-Host missing in the `<VirtualHost *:443>`

Also, you'll have to put the "dot asterisk" in round brackets for the $1 to work (like you did in the RewriteCond for %1):

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1$1 [R=301,L]`